# Why was FlashForward Cancelled?

Tags: flash-forward

Why was this, one of the shows which had the best sci-fi plots, cancelled over 'V'?

It's even rated `7.5` on IMDB, while we see many other lower-rated shows run for a long time!

Is there a chance that another network might bring this show back?  Has any other network mention the possibility?

Answer (score 6):

The show was cancelled due to [plummeting ratings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FlashForward#Reception):

> Although launching to large audiences of 12.47 million viewers in the U.S., the show's ratings rapidly declined to ratings about one-third that figure.

Meanwhile, *V* managed to premiere with lower ratings, but they [lost less of their audience](http://tvseriesfinale.com/tv-show/flashforward-canceled-v-renewed-season-two-15478/) over time:

> On Tuesday, ABC Entertainment President Steve McPherson explained the difficult decision this way, “It was a ‘Sophie’s Choice.’ In the end, FlashForward didn’t engage audiences like we hoped. For V, I get more anecdotal calls and emails than any other show on the schedule. A huge part of rebuilding the network is about taking chances. Some shows just don’t work out.”

Given that all of this happened 3 years ago, and there's been no news of a resurrection of the show, it's safe to assume it's not coming back.